# Im getting CSS and JS not found laravel 9 app

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, tailwind-css

I'm trying to add a custom UI to my Laravel 9 app. So I'm adding extra CSS and JS files to my app.blade.php But looks like its not loading properly.

[image]

As you can see http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/tailwind.output.css  and http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/init-alpine.js  files not loaded. But when i check default http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/app.css file. Its working. But both of these files resides in the same location, which is resources/css/ and resources/js/ folders. Why those custom css and js files not loaded.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html :class="{ 'theme-dark': dark }" x-data="data()" lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">

      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
     
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/tailwind.output.css') }}">

      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js"defer></script>
     
     <script src="{{ asset('js/init-alpine.js') }}" defer></script>

        @livewireStyles

        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        <x-jet-banner />

        <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
            @livewire('navigation-menu')

            <!-- Page Heading -->
            @if (isset($header))
                <header class="bg-white shadow">
                    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                        {{ $header }}
                    </div>
                </header>
            @endif

            <!-- Page Content -->
            <main>
                {{ $slot }}
            </main>
        </div>

        @stack('modals')

        @livewireScripts
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using tailwind CSS, livewire, jetstream and Laravel 9

Comment: try to return to the previous folder ../../js/init-alpine.js

Comment: @KruII still the same, it tried as <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('../../css/tailwind.output.css') }}"> and      <script src="{{ asset('../../js/init-alpine.js') }}" defer></script>

Comment: Does both `tailwind.output.css` and `init-alpine.js` present in public folder? Because laravel load assets from `public` dir not `resources` (your screenshot looks like resources)

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka ooh yeah, now its working :D. im new to laravel . Thanks a lot.

Comment: You may check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mix) link how to deal with assets in your app